# Why isnt page stopping the keypress?

Tags: javascript, html

I have placed the following code at the top of my page in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function stopRKey(evt) {

          console.log(evt.keyCode);

          var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);

          var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);

          console.log(evt.keyCode);

          if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) {
              return false;
          }
      }

      document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

    </script>
```

On one of my pages it is not firing the event when I hit enter. But only one one of my pages the reast seem to work and log a keycode of 13 thus stopping the postback.

Any ideas why this event wouldnt be firing on this certain page?

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: You have to show the rest of your code of the non-working page.

Comment: If this code works on most of your pages, it is probably correct. So to answer your question, you should post more information about the page on which it is not working. One possibility is another event handler listening on a deeper level in your document hierarchy that stops the keypress event from bubbling up.

Comment: Its difficult to post the html as there is too much of it. Is there any way to log what events are happening? using Firebug maybe?

Comment: You already log this event to the console, so just watch that to see if it is fired or not.

Comment: You actually can use firebug to analyze keypress events. Use the command monitorEvents($$("#fieldId"),"keypress") in the console to activate reporting of all keypress events on the field with the id "fieldId". If the keypress events is fired if your type in your input field, also monitor its parent elements. This way, you can see where your event gets lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly simplify the code. There's no reason why this shouldn't work, for `<input type="text">` elements:

```
function stopRKey(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var node = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    console.log(evt.keyCode);

    if (evt.keyCode == 13 && node.nodeName == "INPUT" && node.type == "text") {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there form element on your broken page(s) triggering the postback that is not a text node. Try removing the second part of the condition that prevents the submit, to see what happens:

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But I suspect the event listener is not fired at all, as the OP says: “the rest seem to work and log a keycode of 13”.

Comment: @Marcel - but what of the node type? The console can still log the keyCode but if a non-text node is in focus the form will still be submitted.

Comment: It could be, but he says it doesn't fire and on the other pages the keyCode is logged, so that's before the condition. Anyway, I'll wait for the OP to respond.